# AVD not launching

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm using the ADT plugin from ADT bundle for windows. The problem is when I launch an emulator from AVD manager, the AVD is not launching. The console messages only show the configuration of created AVD. But no AVD showing up.

This is a unique problem which is  unsolved. I tried to search how to troubleshoot this problem from many forum and found out that everyone who face this problem is unsolved.

What should I do? I've wasted much time but still there is no exact solution.

Comment: reinstall your sdk or copy the updated sdk files from other system and replace in your sdk folder.

Comment: Can you launch an emulator from the command line? http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#starting

Comment: No. when I launch from command line, windows pops up message "emulator-arm.exe has stopped working". then what else  I should try? thanks